# How to open a Weka knowledgeFlow file directly from terminal?

Tags: terminal, weka

I wonder is there a way to directly open a knowledgeFlow file from terminal.

Currently, my procedure of opening a kf file is following:

1. go to directory's terminal where weka.jar is at
2. run `wekastart` (a function I put in .bash_profile to export R_HOME, and start Weka)

   function wekastart() {

   ```
   export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources

   java -Xss10M -Xmx4096M -cp .:weka.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
   ```

   }
3. go to `WorkBench`
4. go to `Data Mining Process` (knowledgeflow)
5. ctrl + o to find and open a knowledgeflow file.

I want a new procedure to be as following:

1. go to directory's terminal where weka.jar is at
2. run ' wekastart  "fileName" ' using a pseudo function like the following

   function wekastart(fileName) {

   ```
   export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources

   java -Xss10M -Xmx4096M -cp .:weka.jar weka.gui.WorkBench weka.persp.DataMiningProcess fileName
   ```

   }

Is it possible to achieve this new procedure above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark Hall from [Wekalist](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist), I have developed the following procedure to start a weka knowledgeflow file:

**Solution**

1. go to home directory's terminal, enter `nano .bash_profile`
2. Add the following function to .bash_profile:

   function wekaflstart() {
       export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
       java -Xss10M -Xmx4096M -cp :weka.jar weka.gui.knowledgeflow.KnowledgeFlow "$1"
   }
3. save it, and exit, then in terminal enter `source .bash_profile`
4. go to a directory's terminal (inside there is a weka.jar file) run the following code

   wekaflstart "a kl file's path"

With a few seconds, KnowledgeFlow with the kf file should be open for you.